# Swiftui: Picker getting stuck in catalyst

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui

I've been using SwiftUI for a little while now.
The picker is working correctly on iOS.

However, when I try the same code on macOS, the picker gets stuck after being used once.

[image: Trouble setting picker value]

The specific code I am using is this.

```
let myStatus : Status
var clearStatus = [
    "Never",
    "1 hour",
    "4 hours",
    "Today",
    "This week",
]

@State private var selectedMode = 0

var body: some View {
    return Form {
        Section {
            Text(myStatus.description)

            Picker(selection: $selectedMode, label: Text("Clear after")) {
                ForEach(0 ..< clearStatus.count) {
                    Text(self.clearStatus[$0])
                }
            }
        }
```

https://github.com/hackzilla/slack-status-setter/blob/master/Status%20Setter/SetStatusView.swift#L37

Comment: Did you update to the latest stable version of Mac OS? What version are you using? This was a bug in iOS 13.3 betas but was fixed in the last beta and stable.

Comment: I'm using the latest public release of Xcode and Catalina.

Comment: I have the same issue on an iOS app

Comment: I'm updated to latest version of Xcode (11.3.1), experiencing this issue as well.